# Terminology: what's a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm a beginner and I found several definitions of the term pointer in programming. I would like to know which one is correct (maybe both)?

a - A pointer is a variable that holds a memory address. Given this definition, in the following code `char *msg;`, we can say the variable `msg` is a pointer to a `char`.

b - A pointer is the address of data in memory. Given this definition, the value `0x01020304` returned by the function `malloc` is a pointer.

Comment: What did you find out? What was unclear about the description? How do both descriptions contradict each other?

Comment: Option (b) might be slightly incorrect. Because the value of a pointer is (if valid) the address of a memory location. Whether the location contains actual "data" or not - what does the pointer care? Also the pointer itself is not the address of anything.

Comment: What is "scalar" ? A variable holding a number or a number?

Comment: @EugeneSh. a scalar is usually "something that is not an array".

Comment: What is "int"?  A variable holding an integer number, or a number itself?

Comment: @Quentin - my computer is not an array.  Does it mean that my computer is a scalar?

Comment: You may want to add definition (c): *"A pointer is a data type that "points to" another value stored in memory using its address."* Source: the `pointers` tag description here on SO.

Comment: @user31264 yes, that fits. A server rack, on the other hand, is an array of computers.

Comment: If those really are from some reputable sources I would think they would deliver a reasonable justification for making those statements. It would seem unhelpful to just drop a claim and walk away, and if they did so I wouldn't take a lot of stock in *anything* those sources claimed.

Comment: @Quentin There is a common definition of a scalar. It's a quantity having only magnitude but not a direction. So let's simplify the above: What is quantity? Is it a variable containing number(s) or the number(s)? I feel like in a philosophy course here..

Comment: Also I think you confuse "definition" with "lemma" or other formal concepts here. A definition would be somewhat complete, but both of your statements just describe some partial properties about pointers.

Comment: @grek40: The first is as wrong in that aspect as the second. A pointer need not necessarily point to memory at all. Wrt the language: Only objects are valid memory blocks, anything else does not exist.

Comment: `char *msg;` --> [declare msg as pointer to char](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+*msg%3B)

Answer (score 3):

In a single line, I can say pointer is memory address. Variable it contains the address in memory of another variable.

- The unary or monadic operator & gives the address of a variable.
- The indirection or dereference operator * gives the ``contents of an object pointed to by a pointer.

---

**Brief information about pointers:**

```
int foo;
int *foo_ptr = &foo;
```

- Line 1: This variable occupies some memory. On current mainstream Intel processors, it occupies some(example: 4bytes of memory (because an int is four bytes wide).
- Line2: foo_ptr is declared as a pointer to int. We have initialized it to point to foo.

  [image]

I try to visualise every variable as a box. `foo` is a box that is `sizeof(int)` bytes in size. The location of this box is its address. When you access the address, you actually access the contents of the box it points to.

Answer (score 1):

Address is a value. Pointer is an object that contains addresses.
So in my point of view the first definition is more correct than the second.

If to follow the C Standard then (3. Terms, deﬁnitions, and symbols)

`1 object`

> region of data storage in the execution environment, **the contents of
>   which can represent values**

and (6.2.5 Types)

> — A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object
>   type, called the referenced type. **A pointer type describes an object
>   whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced
>   type**. A pointer type derived from the referenced type T is sometimes
>   called ‘‘pointer to T’’. The construction of a pointer type from a
>   referenced type is called ‘‘pointer type derivation’’. A pointer type
>   is a complete object type.

Comment: Thank you. In the manual page of malloc, it says: "The malloc function returns a pointer to the allocated memory". For me, a function returns a value. In that case, isn't the term pointer synonymous of a value (might be an address) that points to something.

Comment: @Othman The function returns a temporary object of type void * that contains the address of the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer in C is an address semantically associated with a type. No more, no less. A pointer can be assigned to a variable but it doesn't have to be. (One can create pointers in expressions just as when writing (1+2) there's no variable storing the number 3).

Comment: Thank you. How do you call the variable msg in char* msg?